# run shell command in java that prompt for username password

Tags: java, shell, unix, sudo

i am working on restarting apps running on my unix server by java code.
This involve 1) login to server using username and password and then run retsart command which prompt for password this is how its done at shell level

```
$ ssh hostname
users's password:
$ sudo appname start
[sudo] password for user:
 App restarted
```

I am trying to do this using java code i can login to server using ***jsch*** but not sure how to run command which prompts for password.
Can this be done? if yes what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a JSch `ChannelExec` to run the remote command, you can specify the input stream the remote command receives by calling `channel.setInputStream()`. The passed input stream could then contain your password (as a byte array? See `ByteArrayInputStream`)